# How to do i18n translation in Angular 4 for dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization

I have one html template which has display labels which are coming from .ts file dynamically, if I want to translate it dynamically, how can I achieve this?

html

```
<div class="container" *ng-for="let diplaylbl of array">
    <div class="name">{{diplaylbl.firstname}}</div> 
</div>
```

from .ts

```
export public array = [{firstname:"potato"}, {firstname:"tomato"}]
```

Comment: check this for Angular Internationalization https://angular.io/guide/i18n#template-translations

Comment: Prithivi Raj we have gone through this documentation 7 times, no guidelines for dynamic data binding translation

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/ngx-translate/core. it might be useful.

Comment: Let me try, if its useful for me.

Comment: No dear its not working at all yet. thanks

Answer (score -2):

Angular has a useful built-in translate function. You just need to create the i18n folder and files with the translations, I would recommend to group them to keep it ordered: I use different folders for each language (Spanish, English) and inside each, a folder for each section (management), and inside I separate all kinds of strings (ui, alert, instructions, tooltip, etc...), then just a name to recognize it later on.
Add this on the element/container you want translated:

translate="management.ui.accept"

Hope that helps

Comment: please read question again, it seems no connection for angular 4

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it was Angular 4, I was refering to AngularJs and 2

Comment: As per google angular team, they will come with i18n dynamic upgrade after 6 months.